# Calling Partial View JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, partial-views

I have a partial view that contains a function named test().

The view is rendered correctly in the parent view.

I need to call test() from  a parent view JavaScript function.

When I try so, an error occurs: **test() is not defined**.

I am using ASP.net MVC 4.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that the parent view does not know the function exists. And why would it?

Let's say you render the parent, it then looks at all the javascript functions it has access to but as the partial view with the function `test()` isn't created yet, it cannot find it, therefore you have that error.

A way to fix this issue would be to put the function `test()` in the parent.